# JS Source map file doesnt exist - Lighthouse

Tags: javascript, source-maps, lighthouse

Lighthouse can't find source map files even though I have added them just after the script themselves.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.5.0/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.5.0/swiper-bundle.js.map"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how source maps work. You must append `//# sourceMappingURL=swiper-bundle.js.map` at the end of the JS file.

Comment: Is there a way to trick the lighthouse to skip this warning  without actually loading the source map?

Comment: I don't understand your intention. The warning is just a message that Lighthouse could provide more insights, if only a source map were present. If you don't care for that, then just ignore it.

Comment: Anyway, if you're using the node CLI you can pass `--skip-audits=valid-source-maps` to skip this audit.